# React-Router - componentDidMount not called when navigating to URL

Tags: react-router

I'm a little stumped on this one. I defined a route called `classes/:id`. When navigating to that route in the app, the `componentDidMount()` is called. However, when reloading the page or copying and pasting the URL the page completely loads, but the `componentDidMount()` method is not called at all.

From what I have read, the reason is because the same component mounted even though the page is being reloaded which is why the lifecycle method does ever get fired off.

What are some ways to handle this? Your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

`componentDidMount` will not be called again if you are already at a `classes/:id` route. You'll probably want to do something along the lines of:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.id !== prevProps.id) {
    // fetch or other component tasks necessary for rendering
  }
}
```

Comment: To add to my previous answer: the new React Hooks api can simplify this code. Assuming your component is passed a prop for the resource's id which will be used for an api call, you can probably accomplish the same functionality of componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate with useEffect and include the resource's id in the dependency list (i.e. only re-run the useEffect function if the id changes).

Answer (score 2):

I try to avoid any mixins (see willTransitionTo), as they are considered harmful.

Although componentDidMount does not fire when changing routes for the same component, componentWillUpdate and componentWillReceiveProps do.

From there, you can detect parameter changes, and can fire your actions accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

the componentWillReceiveProps,componentDidUpdate lifecycle will receive the new props and then setState to change state to trigger render method.

Answer (score 0):

I just dealt with this exact issue, took me a while to figure out the problem. I'm sure everything previously suggested works great as a solution. How I solved the problem was a bit different though. My componentDidMount function was essentially just providing a state update, so I just moved the functionality directly into the state and bypassed componentDidMount.

Honestly, I'm not sure if this is best practice or not (very happy for feedback if it isn't), but it's running efficiently and works great so far.